# Multiserver support in Mirror [Unity]

Tags: unity, multiplayer, mmo, unity-networking, mirror-networking

Is there any mechanism in Mirror networking library to scale the load in case single server gets overloaded?

There is possibility to use "lobby" conception, but if  you want all players to play together, it is not appropriate.

Comment: From their documentation: https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/general/ccu

Comment: @Zibelas, thanks for the link, but down there is the story of some independent game developers without technical details - looks like they just customized Mirror for their needs. So Mirror has no built-in functionallity to achive this?

Comment: The documentation states that Unity itself is getting problems once the numbers are growing to big. And it is perfectly fine to handle 500 CCU at once. Most games have their own zones on a server once they are to full, which mirror does https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/interest-management/scene